# How do you force maven to execute antrun:run task after all the package tasks in a POM with child modules?

Tags: maven-2

I have a parent POM with a bunch of child modules.
I want to run an *antrun:run* task after all the children have executed a *package* task (I'm using Ant to package my app since i gave up figuring out how to get assembly to work correctly).

I need to have the antrun task execute *after* all the children - but I can't associate it with *package* phase since parent gets "packaged" before children, and i need ant to run afterwards.

Is there a way to do it in one command?

Easy workaround, of course, is to run 2 maven commands:

```
mvn package; mvn antrun:run
```

But i want to do it in one, if possible

```
mvn package antrun:run
```

produces wrong behaviour - it runs antrun:run before child projects' *package* phase.

Ideally, i'd be able to just type

```
mvn package
```

And have that run *package* phase on all children, and then run *antrun:run* on parent.

Answer (score 13):

> I need to have the antrun task execute after all the children - but I can't associate it with package phase since parent gets "packaged" before children, and i need ant to run afterwards.

Create another module that **depends on** all children (so that it will be the last project during a reactor build) and bind your antrun stuff on `package` in this module. Then just run `mvn package` from the root project.

Comment: Genius! i imagine it's not _most maveny_ way to do it, but it certainly works.
Interestingly, i just put my new _packager_ module at the end of modules list, and I didn't have to even depend on anything - it just worked.

thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @toli: You're welcome. But I warmly suggest to declare the dependencies explicitly so that the build order will be calculated in a reliable way. It currently works "by accident".

Comment: Yeah.  For example, if you run 'mvn package -T 4' to enable parallel builds (experimental feature), it'll probably fail because some dependencies won't be available.

Comment: this is great, no google-copy-rename, ant-run, maven-resource plugin could help me, this is the only way I managed to do what I wanted: swap standalone.xml to developer version when running integration tests

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
<inherited>false</inherited>
```

in your plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>    
           <inherited>false</inherited>
              <executions>
                 <execution>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <configuration>

                     <tasks>
                       <ant antfile="buildall.xml">

                       </ant>
                    </tasks>
                 </configuration>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't think it answers the question at all. Inherited(false) just tells that the plugin must not be executed for the current plugin's childrens

Answer (score -3):

First you have to specify *[execution](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Build_Plugins)* for antrun plugin. This will automate the run of that plugin.

Then you have to push maven to run *package plugin* before *antrun plugin*.
You can do that when you place *package plugin* setup before *antrun plugin* setup.

Setup example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase> package </phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>

            <!--
              Place any Ant task here. You can add anything
              you can add between <target> and </target> in a
              build.xml.
            -->

          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I do have exactly your above setup in my POM

not quite sure what you mean by:

_Then you have to push maven to run package plugin before antrun plugin. You can do that when you place package plugin setup before antrun plugin setup._

i don't have a setup for package plugin... so how do i _push it_ to be earlier?

Comment: @toli: You can't "push" anything to be earlier, the default bindings (that you can't "unbind") will always run **before**, period. And there is no *package plugin*.